# A result about companion matrix of a univariate polynomials?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, field-theory

This is a screenshot from an article I am reading. I wanted to ask if the theory and results presented here can be generalized to polynomials over a finite field? If yes, kindly direct me to appropriate references.

[image]

Comment: Yes up to Proposition 1, see e.g. [cyclic decomposition theorem](https://planetmath.org/cyclicdecompositiontheorem).  Parts of Remark 1 doesn't, e.g., we don't have "unit vectors" and hence QR in positive characteristics.

Comment: @user10354138 Thank you for your help/